# Why my n-component in PCA can only be 1 (indices imply 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=1, random_state=42).fit_transform(X_train)
# 43 components according to the graph, but it only allows 1.
pca = pd.DataFrame(pca,columns=['pca'])
#pca
#X_train= pd.concat([X_train,pca],axis=1)
```

If I change the n_components to any other number(for example, 43), it will show the error like this:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (54708, 43), indices imply (54708, 1)
```

I got this in my code to help me know the number of components I should use, which is 43:

```
# find n components to explain variance.
# Code source: https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/pca-how-to-choose-the-number-of-components/
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_rescaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
pca = PCA().fit(data_rescaled)

% matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (24,12)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xi = np.arange(1, 117, step=1)
# The number 117 is to match y, otherwise it gives me error.
y = np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_) 
# (explained_variance_ratio_)
# Percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components.
# np.cumsum
# Return the cumulative sum of the elements along a given axis.


plt.ylim(0.0,1.1)
plt.plot(xi, y, marker='o', linestyle='--', color='b')

plt.xlabel('Number of Components')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 117, step=1)) #change from 0-based array index to 1-based human-readable label

plt.ylabel('Cumulative variance (%)')
plt.title('The number of components needed to explain variance')

plt.axhline(y=0.95, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.text(0.5, 0.85, '95% cut-off threshold', color = 'red', fontsize=16)

ax.grid(axis='x')
plt.show()

# 43 number of components.
```

The graph from the code result:

[image]

Comment: what is your question? first code block or second code block?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, my question is why I can't change the value of ncomponent to the number other than 1, which is the first code block. The second code block just to provide some context .

Comment: I think that the error is coming from this line `pca = pd.DataFrame(pca,columns=['pca'])`, not from the PCA.

Comment: @FlaviaGiammarino Yes, it doesn't allow me to make a dataframe.

Comment: That's because you have 43 columns, but with `columns=['pca']` you are passing only one column name. You could use `columns=['pca' + str(i) for i in range(n_components)]` with `n_components=43` to create a list of 43 column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
pca = pd.DataFrame(pca,columns=[str(i) for i in range(pca.shape[1])])
```

Comment: Thanks. But my X_train.shape is (54708, 116), is there anything wrong in the line:  pca = pd.DataFrame(pca,columns=['pca'])?

Comment: @ShaneLi, I know , this because you want multi-column name base of `pca.shape ` like edit code block